# Determine the mean and variance of a branching process.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

Determine the mean and variance of a branching process with offspring in which an individual either dies, with probability $p$, or is replaced by two progeny, with probability $1−p$.

Would this be a Bernoulli? So the mean would be like $2{p^n}$?

Comment: You need the mean and variance of an actual random variable. A process means that for each time $t$, you have a random variable $X_t$. So do you mean the mean and variance of $X_t$ (as a function of $t$)? Or something else?

Comment: @T_M I am not sure, maybe it me interrupting it wrong. But the question is "Determine the mean and variance of a branching process with offspring in which an individual either dies, with probability p, or is replaced by two progeny, with probability 1−p." So I am not exactly sure....